# Google Big Query view does not preserve data mode

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When creating a view from a table in Google Big Query using the UI, all the fields come with NULLABLE mode and it cannot be changed.

Is there a way of fixing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless something has changed, you need to create the table in advance and then load the data.  We had exactly this problem with code that needed to match an AVRO format and it turned out to be not-easy to solve.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A BigQuery view is defined by a query from a table, the required fields are handled in the that table.

The required fields are the fields (not NULLABLE) that need to be present when loading data in a table. As a view is not meant to load data the mode of the fields doesn't need to be required or nullable.